# Exchange 2010 Tracking Log Explorer only showing internal email

Tags: email, exchange-2010

I have 2 Exchange 2010 servers.  I was looking for a receive time of a certain email so I opened Tracking Log Explorer and added the appropriate Date & Time filters.  All I see are internal emails like reports generated and emailed from other internal servers.

Why don't I see any emails that were received from outside sources?

Comment: Please hover over the tags in your question and **read** the summary. "Questions about configuration and administration of Exchange 2010 servers would be more appropriate for Server Fault."

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and didn't know that was possible.  My bad.

Comment: You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it, or delete this one and post a new question over there ...